# gh-pages fails on `run deploy`

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-pages

GitHub Pages deploy fails and I don't have any idea why.

Already deleted node_modules and reinstalled them.

This is the output from the terminal:

```
> lvl-counter@0.1.0 deploy /Users/9to5dev/github/lvl-counter
> gh-pages -d build

sh: gh-pages: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! lvl-counter@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the lvl-counter@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    enter code here

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/9to5dev/.npm/_logs/2019-01-13T12_42_36_512Z-debug.log
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you have to install npm for every  branch/project individually.

Comment: npm is installed

Answer (score 1):

Did you try installing gh-pages?

```
npm install gh-pages
```